# what is the kth smallest element of an array?

Tags: algorithm

That is the premise of an exercise I'm doing, but i don't get what is the kth element of an array.

For example, the exercise asks me the following input/output:
input: [7, 2, 1, 6, 1] and k = 3
output: 6

I just don't get what's the relation between K and the array.

Answer (score 3):

I think this question is asking you to return the third smallest number in an array with considering duplicates.
For example: `[4,5,2,7,8], 3` should return `5`, whereas in your case it should return `6`

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;

public class FindKthSmallest {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr = new int[]{7,2,1,6,1};
    FindKthSmallest f = new FindKthSmallest();
    System.out.println(f.findKthSmall(arr, 3));
  }

  public int findKthSmall(int[] nums, int k) {
    if (nums == null || nums.length == 0 || k == 0) {
      return -1;
    }

    PriorityQueue<Integer> pq = new PriorityQueue<Integer>(new Comparator<Integer>() {
      @Override
      public int compare(Integer i, Integer j) {
        return j - i;
      }
    });

    for (int i : nums) {
      if (pq.contains(i)) {
        continue;
      }
      pq.offer(i);
      if (pq.size() > k) {
        pq.poll();
      }
    }

    return pq.peek();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

K is just a number, in this example: the `K'th smallest element`. So if K is 2 you're looking for the `2'nd smallest element`

Answer (score 0):

k=3 means that you want the 3rd smallest element in the array.  I don't understand the result, however:

1st smallest: 1
   2nd smallest: 1 (the *other* 1)
   3rd smallest: 2
   4th smallest: 6

When we're talking about array elements in their original order, however, the `k`th element is the one in position `k`.  For instance, if you have

```
arr = [7, 2, 1, 6, 1]
```

Then the 3rd element is `1` (the first one).  However, if your array indexing begins at 0, then `arr[k]` is `arr[3]`, or `6`.

Does that bludgeon the question to death?

Answer (score 0):

If you're confident, that the number of distinct elements is big enough:

```
scala> val arr = Array (7,2,1,6,1)
arr: Array[Int] = Array(7, 2, 1, 6, 1)

scala> arr.distinct.sorted.take(3).last
res85: Int = 6
```

However,

```
scala> arr.distinct.sorted.take(103).last
```

will return the last element, which is 7 but not the correct answer, so you need some check, to return an Option[Int]. Or use a Try (scala.util.Try)

```
Try {arr.distinct.sorted.toList (5)}    
res92: scala.util.Try[Int] = Failure(java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: 5)
scala> Try {arr.distinct.sorted.toList (2)}
res94: scala.util.Try[Int] = Success(6)
```

Since indexing starts at 0, we have to look for index 2, to get the 3rd element.